# Why can't I get the color labelling on a umap.plot() in Python after converting the iris dataset to a data frame with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, visualization

I am trying to generate an aesthetically pleasing plot of the three species of iris in the dataset with the dots in the 2D embedding appropriately colored. I know of other ways to achieve that, but I would like to ask for help working out the wrinkles to get a nice plot with the examples colored appropriately using umap.plot(). Here is the code, which works if the line about the labels in the plot is left out (except that then there are no colors):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import umap
import umap.plot
import holoviews
import datashader
from bokeh.plotting import show, save, output_notebook, output_file
from bokeh.resources import INLINE 


dataset=load_iris()
data=pd.DataFrame(dataset["data"],columns=["Petal length","Petal Width","Sepal Length","Sepal Width"])
data["Species"]=dataset["target"]
data["Species"]=data["Species"].apply(lambda x: dataset["target_names"][x])

embedding = umap.UMAP(n_components=2, metric='hellinger').fit(data.iloc[:,[0,1,2,3]])


f = umap.plot.interactive(embedding, 
                          hover_data=data.iloc[:,[4]],
                          labels= data.iloc[:,[4]],
                          point_size=10)
output_notebook(resources=INLINE)
show(f)
```

To facilitate things, this is the color-less (and useless) code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import umap
import umap.plot
import holoviews
import datashader
from bokeh.plotting import show, save, output_notebook, output_file
from bokeh.resources import INLINE 


dataset=load_iris()
data=pd.DataFrame(dataset["data"],columns=["Petal length","Petal Width","Sepal Length","Sepal Width"])
data["Species"]=dataset["target"]
data["Species"]=data["Species"].apply(lambda x: dataset["target_names"][x])

embedding = umap.UMAP(n_components=2, metric='hellinger').fit(data.iloc[:,[0,1,2,3]])


f = umap.plot.interactive(embedding, 
                          hover_data=data.iloc[:,[4]],
                          point_size=10)
output_notebook(resources=INLINE)
show(f)
```

And this is the different way to actually by-pass the entire data frame creation (which I really don't want to do), and go directly to the dataset to generate the plot - in my opinion it is still very ugly with some dots inconspicuous in light tan, and a huge rendition that forces to scroll through the window, but it is interactive:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import umap
import umap.plot

import holoviews
import datashader
from bokeh.plotting import show, save, output_notebook, output_file
from bokeh.resources import INLINE 

iris = load_iris()
embedding = umap.UMAP(n_components=2, metric='hellinger').fit(iris.data)

category_labels = pd.Series(iris.target).map(dict(zip(range(3),iris.target_names)))
hover_df = pd.DataFrame(category_labels, columns=['category'])
f = umap.plot.interactive(embedding, labels=category_labels,
                          hover_data=hover_df, point_size=10)
output_notebook(resources=INLINE)
show(f)
```

[image]